# Page content not displayed when using "Build Monitor Plugin"

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, cloudbees

**Scenario**

I would like to use the "Build Monitor Plugin" (see https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Monitor+Plugin) with our CloudBees Jenkins instance.

**Steps**

1. Install the "Build Monitor Plugin": [image: Install Build Monitor Plugin]
2. Configure it by creating a new view [image]
3. Add jobs and click "OK": [image]

**Behaviour**

The newly created view is hardly displayed at all: Most of it's content is cut off. [image]

**Expectation**

I expected the monitor to look similar to the monitor I configured on my local machine. [image]

Answer (score 1):

This plugin is apparently incompatible with the DEV@cloud hosted service, apparently due to interactions with the toolbar at the top of the screen. I filed an internal tracking ticket DEV-1651.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I thought so already since, well … it "works on my machine". ;-)

Comment: By the way if this is a paid account you should open a support ticket noting the issue.

Comment: I would've done so, however we're currently in the 2 week Enterprise trial period. The [pricing page](https://www.cloudbees.com/pricing/platform) points to here.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to reproduce your error.Can you give more info of your environment and list of plugins installed.
You can also try installing on fresh server may be in virtual box or on a different machine.

It works fine for me.
I tried with Jenkins version 1.617 and browser Google chrome 44.0.2403.130 (Official Build) m (32-bit) and Build Monitor plugin 1.6+build.159

Comment: The versions at CloudBees are: Jenkins Vers. → 1.609.1.2 and Build Monitor View → 1.3+build.72 These are also the newest version they offer at this time (as far as I know).